# how to update users for Meteor in the console

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

How to I update Meteor users in the console of chrome?
This is without remove any of the insecure and auto publish that was included in the installation.

This is what I typed in my chrome console:

> Meteor.users.update({_id: 'ARfiiEDnk6NbCEzcX'}, {$set: {displayName: 'test'}})

This is what I got:

> 1
>
> debug.js:41 update failed: Access denied

Comment: Obviously you deleted insecure package, and you don't have rights to do any operations on database client-side https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-methods-client-side-operations/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update `Meteor.users` collection because for security reasons writes on this collection are disabled by default regardless the `insecure` package is present or not. There are - however - two exceptions from this rule:

1. The client may create a new user account.
2. A logged in user may updates it's profile, e.g. `{ $set: { 'profile.username': '' } }`

If you really want to update different fields on your users's documents then you have at leasts two possible options:

1. Create a custom method on your server - writes on server are always allowed
2. Add additional `Meteor.users.allow` rule, [look here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow)

I would recommend the first solution because it's more secure.

One more thing. By default, the server only [publishes](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) a few fields from `Meteor.users` collection, including `emails` and `profile`. If you're planning to have more of them and you want them to be available in the browser, you will need to add a custom publish function, e.g.

```
Meteor.publish('myCustomField', function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId },
      { fields: { myCustomField: 1 } });
});
```

And then subscribe on the client side:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myCustomField');
```

Comment: Since you're adding a `displayName` key to the user, just put it in profile. `profile = Meteor.user().profile; profile.displayName = 'test'; Meteor.users.update({_id: 'ARfiiEDnk6NbCEzcX'}, {$set: {profile: profile}})`